# How to alter an array in JS file through a method call from HTML in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js and trying to clear an array which is first instantiated and held on my module:

```
 angular.module(myApp)
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($rootScope){
    var vm = this;

    vm.myArr = ["Clear", "Me"]

    vm.clearer = function(arr) {
       arr = [];
    };

    vm.copier = function(arrToOverwrite, arrToCopy) {
        arrToOverWrite = angular.copy(arrToCopy);
   };
```

And I call this method from my HTML file:

```
    (controller myCtrl is aliased as ctrl)
    <input type="button" ng-click="ctrl.clearer(ctrl.myArr)" value="clear">
```

However, in the JS, it is underlining the `arr`, saying the value is never used. And, say I have something that always displays the value of `myArr` in the HTML, it is unaffected by the changes. I thought since JS is pass by reference, if `myArr` is passed as the reference in the `clearer` method, if it gets updated there, that it would then be updated with that value everywhere?

How would I go about this? I need to use the `clearer` method in other places on other arrays that may be held "in memory" here in the JS file at other times.

Comment: Your updated example, using `angular.copy`, shows off a nifty feature of how `angular.copy` actually works:  "If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy.  Basically, the array is mutated, not reference changed.

Comment: in other words, instead of using `arrToOverWrite = angular.copy(arrToCopy);`, use `angular.copy(arrToCopy, arrToOverWrite);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the function you assign the `arr` param with a reference to `ctrl.myArr`. With the expression `arr = []` you assign `arr` to reference an empty array, but `ctrl.myArr` still points to the original array.

In this case you need to mutate the array directly, by changing the length to 0, for example:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];

var clearer = function(arr) {
  arr.length = 0;
};

clearer(array);

console.log(array);
```

If you need to remove certain items, or add new items, you can use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to overwrite the array with another:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var replacement = [9, 10, 11];

function copier(arrToOverwrite, arrToCopy) {
  arrToOverwrite.splice(0, arrToOverwrite.length, ...arrToCopy); // or angular.copy(arrToCopy, arrToOverwrite)
};

copier(array, replacement);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: That works, but what if I need to do something else to `myArr` like:

`var copier = function(existingArr, newArr) {
     existingArr = angular.copy(newArr);
}`

Comment: @NateH06 the point of confusion is when you make a parameter to a function it is a new pointer if you point it at a new array that doesn't affect other pointers to the original array.  If you modify the array instead of just repointing the local var at a new object then the changes will be reflected, this is a common tripping point.  For the new example would do angular.copy(newArr,existingArr) using the src and destination as arguments so it modifies the data in the original array.

Comment: @NateH06 - see 2nd example

Comment: @shaunhusain , ah, that worked. Interesting though, as all the references point to the original array. I didn't think I made a new array anywhere...

Comment: @shaunhusain - nice idea with the `angular.copy()`.

Comment: When you do [] it is the same as new Array(); just short hand basically.  Yeah this tripped me up for a while too but I've wrangled this beast before :)

Comment: @shaunhusain ... well that's real tricky. Thanks to you both though!